# How to get the node list of lists from string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, tuples

I have a list of lists of strings that stores the node list as strings like this:

```
node_list = ["[(6, {'coordinates': [99, 84]}), (7, {'coordinates': [91, 23]}), (20, {'coordinates': [29, 10]}), (24, {'coordinates': [20, 18]}), (26, {'coordinates': [25, 61]}), (28, {'coordinates': [23, 63]}), (31, {'coordinates': [21, 71]}), (32, {'coordinates': [50, 56]}), (35, {'coordinates': [44, 11]}), (38, {'coordinates': [26, 93]}), (40, {'coordinates': [30, 50]}), (50, {'coordinates': [23, 47]}), (54, {'coordinates': [13, 90]}), (55, {'coordinates': [62, 52]}), (57, {'coordinates': [41, 63]}), (65, {'coordinates': [37, 87]}), (69, {'coordinates': [46, 75]}), (73, {'coordinates': [59, 52]}), (74, {'coordinates': [88, 99]}), (85, {'coordinates': [26, 39]})]",
       "[(2, {'coordinates': [35, 49]}), (3, {'coordinates': [42, 16]}), (11, {'coordinates': [11, 82]}), (15, {'coordinates': [29, 27]}), (19, {'coordinates': [52, 43]}), (20, {'coordinates': [29, 10]}), (35, {'coordinates': [44, 11]}), (36, {'coordinates': [61, 69]}), (49, {'coordinates': [69, 66]}), (50, {'coordinates': [23, 47]}), (52, {'coordinates': [44, 32]}), (62, {'coordinates': [60, 26]}), (70, {'coordinates': [48, 99]}), (71, {'coordinates': [32, 98]}), (74, {'coordinates': [88, 99]}), (85, {'coordinates': [26, 39]}), (86, {'coordinates': [55, 80]}), (88, {'coordinates': [21, 49]}), (97, {'coordinates': [86, 89]}), (99, {'coordinates': [40, 44]})]",
       "[(0, {'coordinates': [98, 87]}), (7, {'coordinates': [91, 23]}), (11, {'coordinates': [11, 82]}), (13, {'coordinates': [94, 59]}), (18, {'coordinates': [26, 85]}), (24, {'coordinates': [20, 18]}), (27, {'coordinates': [69, 95]}), (28, {'coordinates': [23, 63]}), (32, {'coordinates': [50, 56]}), (36, {'coordinates': [61, 69]}), (41, {'coordinates': [40, 78]}), (43, {'coordinates': [20, 61]}), (46, {'coordinates': [49, 55]}), (55, {'coordinates': [62, 52]}), (68, {'coordinates': [73, 54]}), (74, {'coordinates': [88, 99]}), (75, {'coordinates': [60, 24]}), (76, {'coordinates': [40, 70]}), (78, {'coordinates': [89, 39]}), (86, {'coordinates': [55, 80]})]",
       ...,
       "[(7, {'coordinates': [91, 23]}), (10, {'coordinates': [98, 93]}), (11, {'coordinates': [11, 82]}), (12, {'coordinates': [60, 31]}), (17, {'coordinates': [89, 64]}), (21, {'coordinates': [98, 28]}), (33, {'coordinates': [88, 24]}), (34, {'coordinates': [72, 74]}), (35, {'coordinates': [44, 11]}), (39, {'coordinates': [98, 45]}), (41, {'coordinates': [40, 78]}), (51, {'coordinates': [83, 70]}), (52, {'coordinates': [44, 32]}), (59, {'coordinates': [59, 14]}), (61, {'coordinates': [12, 64]}), (72, {'coordinates': [65, 73]}), (75, {'coordinates': [60, 24]}), (88, {'coordinates': [21, 49]}), (89, {'coordinates': [35, 17]}), (97, {'coordinates': [86, 89]})]",
       "[(10, {'coordinates': [98, 93]}), (13, {'coordinates': [94, 59]}), (23, {'coordinates': [75, 22]}), (27, {'coordinates': [69, 95]}), (33, {'coordinates': [88, 24]}), (48, {'coordinates': [18, 76]}), (50, {'coordinates': [23, 47]}), (61, {'coordinates': [12, 64]}), (62, {'coordinates': [60, 26]}), (69, {'coordinates': [46, 75]}), (70, {'coordinates': [48, 99]}), (71, {'coordinates': [32, 98]}), (76, {'coordinates': [40, 70]}), (81, {'coordinates': [41, 21]}), (84, {'coordinates': [26, 29]}), (87, {'coordinates': [14, 44]}), (88, {'coordinates': [21, 49]}), (89, {'coordinates': [35, 17]}), (90, {'coordinates': [12, 20]}), (95, {'coordinates': [23, 60]})]",
       "[(2, {'coordinates': [35, 49]}), (3, {'coordinates': [42, 16]}), (12, {'coordinates': [60, 31]}), (13, {'coordinates': [94, 59]}), (25, {'coordinates': [51, 82]}), (33, {'coordinates': [88, 24]}), (45, {'coordinates': [10, 60]}), (48, {'coordinates': [18, 76]}), (55, {'coordinates': [62, 52]}), (67, {'coordinates': [26, 81]}), (69, {'coordinates': [46, 75]}), (70, {'coordinates': [48, 99]}), (71, {'coordinates': [32, 98]}), (84, {'coordinates': [26, 29]}), (86, {'coordinates': [55, 80]}), (90, {'coordinates': [12, 20]}), (95, {'coordinates': [23, 60]}), (96, {'coordinates': [70, 17]}), (98, {'coordinates': [35, 76]}), (99, {'coordinates': [40, 44]})]"]
```

How can I turn this list into a list of lists of tuples like this?

```
node_list = [[(6, {'coordinates': [99, 84]}), (7, {'coordinates': [91, 23]}), (20, {'coordinates': [29, 10]}), (24, {'coordinates': [20, 18]}), (26, {'coordinates': [25, 61]}), (28, {'coordinates': [23, 63]}), (31, {'coordinates': [21, 71]}), (32, {'coordinates': [50, 56]}), (35, {'coordinates': [44, 11]}), (38, {'coordinates': [26, 93]}), (40, {'coordinates': [30, 50]}), (50, {'coordinates': [23, 47]}), (54, {'coordinates': [13, 90]}), (55, {'coordinates': [62, 52]}), (57, {'coordinates': [41, 63]}), (65, {'coordinates': [37, 87]}), (69, {'coordinates': [46, 75]}), (73, {'coordinates': [59, 52]}), (74, {'coordinates': [88, 99]}), (85, {'coordinates': [26, 39]})],
             [(2, {'coordinates': [35, 49]}), (3, {'coordinates': [42, 16]}), (11, {'coordinates': [11, 82]}), (15, {'coordinates': [29, 27]}), (19, {'coordinates': [52, 43]}), (20, {'coordinates': [29, 10]}), (35, {'coordinates': [44, 11]}), (36, {'coordinates': [61, 69]}), (49, {'coordinates': [69, 66]}), (50, {'coordinates': [23, 47]}), (52, {'coordinates': [44, 32]}), (62, {'coordinates': [60, 26]}), (70, {'coordinates': [48, 99]}), (71, {'coordinates': [32, 98]}), (74, {'coordinates': [88, 99]}), (85, {'coordinates': [26, 39]}), (86, {'coordinates': [55, 80]}), (88, {'coordinates': [21, 49]}), (97, {'coordinates': [86, 89]}), (99, {'coordinates': [40, 44]})],
             [(0, {'coordinates': [98, 87]}), (7, {'coordinates': [91, 23]}), (11, {'coordinates': [11, 82]}), (13, {'coordinates': [94, 59]}), (18, {'coordinates': [26, 85]}), (24, {'coordinates': [20, 18]}), (27, {'coordinates': [69, 95]}), (28, {'coordinates': [23, 63]}), (32, {'coordinates': [50, 56]}), (36, {'coordinates': [61, 69]}), (41, {'coordinates': [40, 78]}), (43, {'coordinates': [20, 61]}), (46, {'coordinates': [49, 55]}), (55, {'coordinates': [62, 52]}), (68, {'coordinates': [73, 54]}), (74, {'coordinates': [88, 99]}), (75, {'coordinates': [60, 24]}), (76, {'coordinates': [40, 70]}), (78, {'coordinates': [89, 39]}), (86, {'coordinates': [55, 80]})],
             ...,
             [(7, {'coordinates': [91, 23]}), (10, {'coordinates': [98, 93]}), (11, {'coordinates': [11, 82]}), (12, {'coordinates': [60, 31]}), (17, {'coordinates': [89, 64]}), (21, {'coordinates': [98, 28]}), (33, {'coordinates': [88, 24]}), (34, {'coordinates': [72, 74]}), (35, {'coordinates': [44, 11]}), (39, {'coordinates': [98, 45]}), (41, {'coordinates': [40, 78]}), (51, {'coordinates': [83, 70]}), (52, {'coordinates': [44, 32]}), (59, {'coordinates': [59, 14]}), (61, {'coordinates': [12, 64]}), (72, {'coordinates': [65, 73]}), (75, {'coordinates': [60, 24]}), (88, {'coordinates': [21, 49]}), (89, {'coordinates': [35, 17]}), (97, {'coordinates': [86, 89]})],
             [(10, {'coordinates': [98, 93]}), (13, {'coordinates': [94, 59]}), (23, {'coordinates': [75, 22]}), (27, {'coordinates': [69, 95]}), (33, {'coordinates': [88, 24]}), (48, {'coordinates': [18, 76]}), (50, {'coordinates': [23, 47]}), (61, {'coordinates': [12, 64]}), (62, {'coordinates': [60, 26]}), (69, {'coordinates': [46, 75]}), (70, {'coordinates': [48, 99]}), (71, {'coordinates': [32, 98]}), (76, {'coordinates': [40, 70]}), (81, {'coordinates': [41, 21]}), (84, {'coordinates': [26, 29]}), (87, {'coordinates': [14, 44]}), (88, {'coordinates': [21, 49]}), (89, {'coordinates': [35, 17]}), (90, {'coordinates': [12, 20]}), (95, {'coordinates': [23, 60]})],
             [(2, {'coordinates': [35, 49]}), (3, {'coordinates': [42, 16]}), (12, {'coordinates': [60, 31]}), (13, {'coordinates': [94, 59]}), (25, {'coordinates': [51, 82]}), (33, {'coordinates': [88, 24]}), (45, {'coordinates': [10, 60]}), (48, {'coordinates': [18, 76]}), (55, {'coordinates': [62, 52]}), (67, {'coordinates': [26, 81]}), (69, {'coordinates': [46, 75]}), (70, {'coordinates': [48, 99]}), (71, {'coordinates': [32, 98]}), (84, {'coordinates': [26, 29]}), (86, {'coordinates': [55, 80]}), (90, {'coordinates': [12, 20]}), (95, {'coordinates': [23, 60]}), (96, {'coordinates': [70, 17]}), (98, {'coordinates': [35, 76]}), (99, {'coordinates': [40, 44]})]]
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: You have a list of strings.  Each string needs to pass through `eval` or `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks a lot. I worked.